# (Re)Creating Treeview by selecting a GridViewRow on the Masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, master-pages, postback

So, I have a GridView on my MasterPage with an onclick Event which returns the ID (there are device components in this grid and I need their ID from the database) from that row.

**The Onclick event which is bound in the RowDataBound event**

```
e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.selectionGridView, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
```

**When I click a row the SelectedIndexChanged Event gets fired**

```
protected void selectionGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView selectedGridView = sender as GridView;
        //Saves the Database ID of the selected data
        Session["selectedDevID"] = selectedGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;

        _Auswahl.FillTree();
    }
```

**And this piece of code calls a method from the page I want to show a Treeview with more stuff etc.**

```
_Auswahl.FillTree();
```

Everthing is fine, all methods are called correctly, but on the ***_Auswahl*** Page, I can't add things to the TreeView (or to the Page at all). All my controls return a NullReferenceExeption, and if I initialize them, then this stuff won't show up

I tried everything, I guess I miss some little thing or forgot something, but I can't get this thing right ._.

Edit: I don't want to Redirect to that Page again, I want to "refresh" the treeview (which is located in an UpdatePanel)

Edit2:

**This is my ___FillTree()*_* Methode (Excluded the whole Linq stuff etc etc und left just some basic stuff)**

```
public void FillTree()
    { 
        //Add child node value
        TreeNode child = new TreeNode("Manager");

        //Add parent value
        TreeNode parent = new TreeNode("Development");

        //Add child to parent
        parent .ChildNodes.Add(child);

        //Add parent to tree
        TreeView1 = new TreeView();
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(parent);

        TreeView1.DataBind();
        TreeView1.ExpandAll();
    }
```

Comment: Is FillTree method defined in _Auswahl class static? It seems to be looking at the way you call it. Can you show us that method code too?

Comment: Sure. I'll edit my post.